# 'UnicodeDecodeError' in Tweepy API

Tags: python, api, twitter, bots, tweepy

Alright, so here's what I have:

```
    import tweepy 
    import time

    #login credentials twitter account
    consumer_key = '------'
    consumer_secret = '-----'
    access_token = '-----'
    access_secret = '-----'

    #login
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    search_query = "I'm"


    user = api.me()
    print(user.name)

    max_tweets = 100

    #reply
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,         q=search_query).items(max_tweets):
        c=tweet.text.encode('utf8')
        c=c.replace("im ","")
        answer="@"+tweet.user.screen_name+" Hi " + c + ", I'm Dad!"
        print ("Reply:",answer)

   api.update_status(status=answer,in_reply_to_status_id=tweet.id)
   time.sleep(300) #every 5 minutes
```

Now, the error I recieve is this:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\twitterbotdad.py", line 26, in <module>
        answer="@"+tweet.user.screen_name+" Hi " + c + ", I'm Dad!"
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 33: ordinal not in range(128)
    >>> 
    ===================
```

Would anyone mind assisting me? I have been trying to fix this, but I am not getting anywhere.

Comment: IDK about python 2.7 (you should be using 3 anyway), but in 3 you can just call `decode('utf-8')` (like this: `tweet.user.screen_name.decode('utf-8')`) to decode it. It's hard for anyone to come up with an answer because this question is hard to reproduce (:

Comment: You need to be careful when working with Unicode. Don't mix Unicode strings with UTF-8 bytes. Unicode in Python 3 is a lot easier. In the mean time, please see https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Answer (score 0):

have you tried placing the following lines on top of your code?

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

i also edited [my answer to your query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52339729/twitter-bot-with-tweepy-python/52345852#52345852) a few days ago, in case you didn't see it. :)

/ogs